# How to assign values to an array of objects in Delphi

Tags: arrays, json, object, delphi

I have an array of TBoek and and a loop that is supposed to assign values to each of the elements of the array. What happens instead is that the array ends up with the exact same values in each index. Perhaps my order of processing is incorrect or I'm incorrectly assigning values to the array, but either way I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
procedure TBoek.MaakArray;
var
  i: integer;
  sTitel, sOuteur, sISBN, sUitgewer, sPrys, sI: string;
  boek: TBoek;
begin
  boek := TBoek.Create;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
{$REGION 'Parse JSON om eienskappe van boek te kry'}
    sI := IntToStr(i);

    sTitel := JSONFile.GetValue<string>('items[' + sI + '].volumeInfo.title');
    try
      sOuteur := JSONFile.GetValue<string>
        ('items[' + sI + '].volumeInfo.authors[0]');
    except
      sOuteur := '<none>'
    end;
    try
      sISBN := JSONFile.GetValue<string>
        ('items[' + sI + '].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier');
    except
      sISBN := '<none>'
    end;
    try
      sUitgewer := JSONFile.GetValue<string>
        ('items[' + sI + '].volumeInfo.publisher');
    except
      sUitgewer := '<none>'
    end;
    try
      sPrys := JSONFile.GetValue<string>
        ('items[' + sI + '].saleInfo.listPrice.amount');
    except
      sPrys := '0';
    end;
{$ENDREGION}
    arrBoeke[i] := boek;
    with arrBoeke[i] do
    begin
      SetTitel(sTitel);
      SetOuteur(sOuteur);
      SetISBN(sISBN);
      SetUitgewer(sUitgewer);
      SetPrys(sPrys);
    end;

  end;///end of for loop

end;
```

The `Set` functions all follow this format:

```
procedure TBoek.SetTitel(BoekTitel: string);
begin
  fTitel := BoekTitel;
end;
```

This is the `GetString` function:

```
function TBoek.GetString: string;
begin
  Result := GetTitel + #13#10 + GetOuteur + #13#10 + GetISBN + #13#10 +
    GetUitgewer + #13#10 + GetPrys + #13#10 + #13#10;
end;
```

And the `GetTitel`,`GetOuteur` etc. functions all follow the same format:

```
function TBoek.GetTitel: string;
begin
  Result := fTitel;
end;
```

What I want is to call:

```
for I := 0 to 9 do
   begin
     ShowMessage(arrBoeke[i].GetString);
   end;
```

and access the values in the array one at a time, instead each value is the same.

Comment: Where is your array declaration?

Comment: @nolaspeaker It is declared as a global variable as `arrBoeke: array [0 .. 9] of TBoek;`

Comment: Ask yourself how many different instances of the class you created

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Only one. But if I put `boek := TBoek.Create;` inside the for loop, all the values of the array are blank. So what would you suggest to fix my problem?

Comment: If you want 10 different instances, you need to create 10 instances. You code creates one and all elements of the array refer to that one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. Got it now: I made a for loop in front of mine that creates a different instance for each ```var arrBk : array[0..9] of TBoek;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    arrBk[i] := TBoek.Create;
  end;```

Comment: You can do it all in one loop.

Comment: You could have done it in your existing loop, by changing `arrBoeke[i] := boek;` to `arrBoeke[i] := TBoek.Create;`